# вывод цены в зависимости от количества товара в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть блоки с товаром в категории , нужно что бы при нажатие на + или - считалась цена в зависимости от количества товара

```html
<div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 14px;">
 <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">220&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span></span>
</div>
<div class="quantity" style="margin: 15px 0 0;">
   <button class="quantity-minus button">-</button>
   <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="text-center" data-product_id="375" data-min="1" data-max="999999" style="width: 50px;margin: 0 10px;font-weight: bold;">
   <button class="quantity-plus button">+</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Пришлите ту часть, где получаете стоимость товара, так как в поле span она будет меняться. Нужна начальная стоимость.

Comment: <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Читайте внимательно комментарии.

```php
<?php
$price = "100"; // сумма одного товара. У Вас это $product->get_price_html().
?>

<div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 14px;">
    <span class="price"><span id="summ" class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><?php echo $price; ?><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span></span>
</div>
<div class="quantity" style="margin: 15px 0 0;">
    <button id="minus" class="quantity-minus button">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="text-center" data-product_id="375" data-min="1" data-max="999999" style="width: 50px;margin: 0 10px;font-weight: bold;">
    <button id="plus" class="quantity-plus button">+</button>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
    minus.onclick = function () { // При нажатии кнопки минус (Добавлен id) выполняем действие
        var a = "<?php echo $price ?>"; // получаем сумму товара из переменной php
        var z = document.getElementById("summ").innerHTML; // Получаем сумму товаров из формы.
        z = Number(z.replace(/\D+/g,"")); // Выбираем из суммы товаров только числа
        var summ = z - Number(a); // Отнимаем от общей суммы - сумму одного товара.
        if (summ < 0){ // Если получившееся число меньше 0, то ставим 0, чтобы не было минусов.
            summ = 0
        }
        document.getElementById("summ").innerHTML = summ; //Вставляем число в html
    };
    plus.onclick = function () {
        var a = "<?php echo $price ?>";
        var z = document.getElementById("summ").innerHTML;
        z = Number(z.replace(/\D+/g,""));
        var summ = z + Number(a);
        document.getElementById("summ").innerHTML = summ;
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `.priceValue` элемент, где итоговая цена;
- `.button-plus` кнопка плюс;
- `.button-minus` кнопка минус;
- `.totalItems` инпут с количеством

```js
let priceValue = document.querySelector(".priceValue");
let plusBtn = document.querySelector(".button-plus");
let minusBtn = document.querySelector(".button-minus");
let totalItems = document.querySelector(".totalItems");

//цена товара
let itemPrice = 220;

//Обработчик нажатия на плюс
plusBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   totalItems.value++ && change();
});

//Обработчик нажатия на минус
minusBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
totalItems.value-- && change();
});

// изменение .priceValue при изменении в input
const change = () => {
 totalItems.value < 1 && (totalItems.value = 1);
 priceValue.textContent = itemPrice * totalItems.value;
}
```

```css
input.totalItems::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input.totalItems::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 14px;">
    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="priceValue">220</span>&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="quantity" style="margin: 15px 0 0;">
    <button class="button-minus quantity-minus button">-</button>
    <input onChange="change()" type="number" name="quantity" value="1" class="totalItems text-center" data-product_id="375" data-min="1" data-max="999999" style="width: 50px;margin: 0 10px;font-weight: bold;">
    <button class="button-plus quantity-plus button">+</button>
</div>
```